# Columns missing after scraping website with python & selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

After running code it displays 2 out of 4 required columns ([see output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGwBz.png)).

I modified the way the lists are appended when the elements with the `xpath://a[@class=\'outcome\` are missing. I assigned the value 'N/A' to the respective variables (home_team, away_team, home_odd, away_odd). Then, I appended these variables to the lists directly. This ensures that all lists have the same length but the column containing the away teams and the column containing the home odds is missing after running the code:

```
games = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,
                         '//div[@class="event-card__wrapper" and not(contains(., "//a[@class=\'outcome\']"))]')

for game in games:
    home_team_element = None
    away_team_element = None
    home_odd_element = None
    away_odd_element = None

    try:
        home_team_element = game.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.competitors__wrapper > div:nth-child(1)')
        home_team = home_team_element.text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        home_team = 'N/A'

    try:
        away_team_element = game.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.competitors__wrapper > div:nth-child(2)')
        away_team = away_team_element.text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        away_team = 'N/A'

    try:
        home_odd_element = game.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.market__list > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)')
        home_odd = home_odd_element.text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        home_odd = 'N/A'

    try:
        away_odd_element = game.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.market__list > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1)')
        away_odd = away_odd_element.text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        away_odd = 'N/A'

pm_homebbwin_teams_list.append(home_team)
pm_awaybbwin_teams_list.append(away_team)
pm_homebbwin_odds_list.append(home_odd)
pm_awaybbwin_odds_list.append(away_odd)

pm_dict = {
    'Parimatch BBHome Team (winmkt)': pm_homebbwin_teams_list,
    'Parimatch BBAway Team (winmkt)': pm_awaybbwin_teams_list,
    'Parimatch BBHome Odd (winmkt)': pm_homebbwin_odds_list,
    'Parimatch BBAway Odd (winmkt)': pm_awaybbwin_odds_list
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pm_dict)
print(df)
```

Comment: How are the lists initiated? That isn't in this code and might be related to the error. 
Additionally, a couple quick notes on code. This snippet isn't properly indented, although the code in imgur is. It doesn't seem necessary to initiate `home_team_element` and the other ones. And all the try statements are the same, so a function can be written to simplify it.
Lastly, the output image has a "..." in it - try writing to a csv and see if the columns are actually missing. They might just not be displayed within that terminal.

Comment: ok let me try writing to a csv. thanks